# how sign correctly xml python using signxml?

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, public-key-encryption, xml-signature

Hi everybody i'm trying create and sign xml from json data.
I retrieve my object as json from this i create the xml with my xsd file.

when i sign at the output file i can't see  (this is empty on my xml)
and the nodes's sign is inline. How i can get same result as example?

P.S: I've got xsd schema for the the sign but i don't kown how tp use with signxml

**part where i sign xml**

```
key = open('../../firma/privatekey.pem','rb').read()
cert = open('../../firma/Octav.crs','rb').read()
print(cert)
signed_root=XMLSigner(method=signxml.methods.enveloped, signature_algorithm='rsa-sha256', digest_algorithm='sha256', c14n_algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315#WithComments").sign(root, key=key, cert=cert)
ET.ElementTree(signed_root).write('factura_firmada.xml')
```

code complete
**with libraries**

```
import xmlschema
from xml.etree.cElementTree import ElementTree
import json

from lxml import etree
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from signxml import XMLSigner, XMLVerifier
import signxml

dataJSON={
    '@xmlns:xsi': 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance', 
    '@xmlns:default': 'http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#', 
    '@xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation': 'facturaElectronicaCompraVenta.xsd', 
    'cabecera': 
        {'nitEmisor': 1003579028, 
        'razonSocialEmisor': 'Carlos Loza', 
        'municipio': 'La Paz', 
        'telefono': '2846005', 
        'numeroFactura': 1, 
        'cuf': '44AAEC00DBD34C819B4D7AFD5F91900D3A059E06A467A75AC82F24C74', 
        'cufd': 'BQUE+QytqQUDBKVUFOSVRPQkxVRFZNVFVJBMDAwMDAwM', 
        'codigoSucursal': 0, 
        'direccion': 'AV. JORGE LOPEZ #123', 
        'codigoPuntoVenta': {'@xsi:nil': 'true'}, 
        'fechaEmision': '2021-10-07T09:01:24.178', 
        'nombreRazonSocial': 'Mi razon social', 
        'codigoTipoDocumentoIdentidad': 1, 
        'numeroDocumento': '5115889', 
        'complemento': {'@xsi:nil': 'true'}, 
        'codigoCliente': '51158891', 
        'codigoMetodoPago': 1, 
        'numeroTarjeta': {'@xsi:nil': 'true'}, 
        'montoTotal': 99, 
        'montoTotalSujetoIva': 99, 
        'codigoMoneda': 1, 
        'tipoCambio': 1, 
        'montoTotalMoneda': 99, 
        'montoGiftCard': {'@xsi:nil': 'true'}, 
        'descuentoAdicional': 1, 
        'codigoExcepcion': {'@xsi:nil': 'true'}, 
        'cafc': {'@xsi:nil': 'true'}, 
        'leyenda': 'Ley N° 453: Tienes derecho a recibir información sobre las características y contenidos de los\n            servicios que utilices.\n        ', 
        'usuario': 'pperez', 
        'codigoDocumentoSector': 1}, 
        'detalle': [
            {'actividadEconomica': '451010', 
            'codigoProductoSin': 49111, 
            'codigoProducto': 
            'JN-131231', 
            'descripcion': 
            'JUGO DE NARANJA EN VASO', 
            'cantidad': 1, 
            'unidadMedida': 1, 
            'precioUnitario': 100, 
            'montoDescuento': 0, 
            'subTotal': 100, 
            'numeroSerie': '124548', 
            'numeroImei': '545454'}], 
    }


dati=json.dumps(dataJSON)
xml=xmlschema.from_json(dati, schema=schema)

ElementTree(xml).write('myxml.xml')

#Now i open the file to sign but I don't sure if correct open file write or if i can sign without save before file

el= ET.parse('myxml.xml')
root=el.getroot()

key = open('../../firma/privatekey.pem','rb').read()
cert = open('../../firma/Octav.crs','rb').read()
print(cert)
signed_root=XMLSigner(method=signxml.methods.enveloped, signature_algorithm='rsa-sha256', digest_algorithm='sha256', c14n_algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315#WithComments").sign(root, key=key, cert=cert)
ET.ElementTree(signed_root).write('factura_firmada.xml')

print('file writed!')
```

this is the result i need

```
<facturaElectronicaCompraVenta
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="facturaElectronicaCompraVenta.xsd">
    <cabecera>
        <nitEmisor>1003579028</nitEmisor>
        <razonSocialEmisor>Carlos Loza</razonSocialEmisor>
        <municipio>La Paz</municipio>
        <telefono>2846005</telefono>
        <numeroFactura>1</numeroFactura>
        <cuf>44AAEC00DBD34C819B4D7AFD5F91900D3A059E06A467A75AC82F24C74</cuf>
        <cufd>BQUE+QytqQUDBKVUFOSVRPQkxVRFZNVFVJBMDAwMDAwM</cufd>
        <codigoSucursal>0</codigoSucursal>
        <direccion>AV. JORGE LOPEZ #123</direccion>
        <codigoPuntoVenta xsi:nil="true"/>
        <fechaEmision>2021-10-07T09:01:24.178</fechaEmision>
        <nombreRazonSocial>Mi razon social</nombreRazonSocial>
        <codigoTipoDocumentoIdentidad>1</codigoTipoDocumentoIdentidad>
        <numeroDocumento>5115889</numeroDocumento>
        <complemento xsi:nil="true"/>
        <codigoCliente>51158891</codigoCliente>
        <codigoMetodoPago>1</codigoMetodoPago>
        <numeroTarjeta xsi:nil="true"/>
        <montoTotal>99</montoTotal>
        <montoTotalSujetoIva>99</montoTotalSujetoIva>
        <codigoMoneda>1</codigoMoneda>
        <tipoCambio>1</tipoCambio>
        <montoTotalMoneda>99</montoTotalMoneda>
        <montoGiftCard xsi:nil="true"/>
        <descuentoAdicional>1</descuentoAdicional>
        <codigoExcepcion xsi:nil="true"/>
        <cafc xsi:nil="true"/>
        <leyenda>Ley N° 453: Tienes derecho a recibir información sobre las características y contenidos de los servicios que utilices. </leyenda>
        <usuario>pperez</usuario>
        <codigoDocumentoSector>1</codigoDocumentoSector>
    </cabecera>
    <detalle>
        <actividadEconomica>451010</actividadEconomica>
        <codigoProductoSin>49111</codigoProductoSin>
        <codigoProducto>JN-131231</codigoProducto>
        <descripcion>JUGO DE NARANJA EN VASO</descripcion>
        <cantidad>1</cantidad>
        <unidadMedida>1</unidadMedida>
        <precioUnitario>100</precioUnitario>
        <montoDescuento>0</montoDescuento>
        <subTotal>100</subTotal>
        <numeroSerie>124548</numeroSerie>
        <numeroImei>545454</numeroImei>
    </detalle>
    <Signature
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <SignedInfo>
            <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/>
            <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"/>
            <Reference URI="">
                <Transforms>
                    <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
                    <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315#WithComments"/>
                </Transforms>
                <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
                <DigestValue>WmFvnKBZIr9D37PaYuxM3aoXVu9nDZT+2MI1I+RUh8s=</DigestValue>
            </Reference>
        </SignedInfo>
        <SignatureValue> itb123fGGhh12DpFDFas34ASDAPpSSSSadasDasAS1smkRsj5ksdjasd8asdkasjd8asdkas8asdk21v a1qf+kBKLwF39mj+5zKo1qf+kBKLD42qD/+yxSMMS6DM5SywPxO1oyjnSZtObIe/45fdS4sE9+aNOn UncYUlSDAPpSSSSadasgIMWwlX2XMJ4SDAPpSSSSadas6qihJt/3dEIdta1RETSDAPpSSSSadas9S2W ALbT3VV8pjLqikVLcSDAPpSSSSadaseCKG8abcdssM0Wm8p+5grNNpSDAPpSSSSadasy4TvT4C3xS 70zSbKWeBUUglRcU8FECEcacu+UJaBCgRW0S3Q== </SignatureValue>
        <KeyInfo>
            <X509Data>
                <X509Certificate> TIIEuzCCZ7OgZIZsdZsDSZDSsdZsdSZSDZSDZKoZIhvcNZQEZBQZgbUxCzZZBgNVBZYTZkZ TIIEuzCCZ7OgZIZsdZsDSZDSsdZsdSZSDZSDZKoZIhvcNZQEZBQZgbUxCzZZBgNVBZYTZkZ bnRhbTlsbGZZZ1dVzdG9zLTdvYi5ibzCCZSIDQYZKoZIhvcNZQEBBQZDgasdaACZQoCggEB TIIEuzCCZ7OgZIZsdZsDSZDSsdZsdSZSDZSDZKoZIhvcNZQEZBQZgbUxCzZZBgNVBZYTZkZ bnRhbTlsbGZZZ1dVzdG9zLTdvYi5ibzCCZSIDQYZKoZIhvcNZQEBBQZDgasdaACZQoCggEB TIIEuzCCZ7OgZIZsdZsDSZDSsdZsdSZSDZSDZKoZIhvcNZQEZBQZgbUxCzZZBgNVBZYTZkZ bnRhbTlsbGZZZ1dVzdG9zLTdvYi5ibzCCZSIDQYZKoZIhvcNZQEBBQZDgasdaACZQoCggEB k/IsZZEBEETRTEQYDVQQZEoxTDZzNTc5TDI4TTITZYZKoZIhvcNZQkBZiNhcT5vbGQucXVp bnRhbTlsbGZZZ1dVzdG9zLTdvYi5ibzCCZSIDQYZKoZIhvcNZQEBBQZDgasdaACZQoCggEB bnRhbTlsbGZZZ1dVzdG9zLTdvYi5ibzCCZSIDQYZKoZIhvcNZQEBBQZDgasdaACZQoCggEB kTIh+T9dIRZ9GghiSZbP2Zk082ycgic2ZepdZLu7p2LEUZUhTXSXGZQkO4o/ZNZZk0ZQKgi bnRhbTlsbGZZZ1dVzdG9zLTdvYi5ibzCCZSIDQYZKoZIhvcNZQEBBQZDgasdaACZQoCggEB V8ZVyTkIDRCTcBYZO4ZZ8oV1UTbQEiDZZOYTZDHT2ZRy+kS+OzCdpZZKZZyds0ZClCZRlTg bnRhbTlsbGZZZ1dVzdG9zLTdvYi5ibzCCZSIDQYZKoZIhvcNZQEBBQZDgasdaACZQoCggEB Z1UdDQEZIE8DZuBgNVHREEZzZlhiNhcT5vZZZXVpbnRhbTlsbGZZZ1dVzdG9zLTdvYi5i7Z bzBRBgNVHR8ESZBITEZgRKBChkBodHRczovL2Rlc2ZycT9sbG8uYRzZIuZ29iLTZvL2Rlc2 bnRhbTlsbGZZZ1dVzdG9zLTdvYi5ibzCCZSIDQYZKoZIhvcNZQEBBQZDgasdaACZQoCggEB NRrZKQl3YhKZKRSZyeegVZIiXlYeEyOe5qdn3XdyTCDkz4bTn02KbcsnZP7oVTqsodBSd0B ptrxqoqeZHhGBzEl5/vxDS/Sx4eO7ZXd1T4HtZntETdsZXZuPZZt4Vr57R/hqdZeTkk7uO9 bnRhbTlsbGZZZ1dVzdG9zLTdvYi5ibzCCZSIDQYZKoZIhvcNZQEBBQZDgasdaACZQoCggEB YB+PC1LO7gnh4Zz9UsYb0YBG </X509Certificate>
            </X509Data>
        </KeyInfo>
    </Signature>
</facturaElectronicaCompraVenta>
```

this my result

```
<facturaElectronicaCompraVenta xmlns:ns1="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="facturaElectronicaCompraVenta.xsd">
    <cabecera>
        <nitEmisor>1003579028</nitEmisor>
        <razonSocialEmisor>Carlos Loza</razonSocialEmisor>
        <municipio>La Paz</municipio>
        <telefono>2846005</telefono>
        <numeroFactura>1</numeroFactura>
        <cuf>44AAEC00DBD34C819B4D7AFD5F91900D3A059E06A467A75AC82F24C74</cuf>
        <cufd>BQUE+QytqQUDBKVUFOSVRPQkxVRFZNVFVJBMDAwMDAwM</cufd>
        <codigoSucursal>0</codigoSucursal>
        <direccion>AV. JORGE LOPEZ #123</direccion>
        <codigoPuntoVenta xsi:nil="true" />
        <fechaEmision>2021-10-07T09:01:24.178</fechaEmision>
        <nombreRazonSocial>Mi razon social</nombreRazonSocial>
        <codigoTipoDocumentoIdentidad>1</codigoTipoDocumentoIdentidad>
        <numeroDocumento>5115889</numeroDocumento>
        <complemento xsi:nil="true" />
        <codigoCliente>51158891</codigoCliente>
        <codigoMetodoPago>1</codigoMetodoPago>
        <numeroTarjeta xsi:nil="true" />
        <montoTotal>99</montoTotal>
        <montoTotalSujetoIva>99</montoTotalSujetoIva>
        <codigoMoneda>1</codigoMoneda>
        <tipoCambio>1</tipoCambio>
        <montoTotalMoneda>99</montoTotalMoneda>
        <montoGiftCard xsi:nil="true" />
        <descuentoAdicional>1</descuentoAdicional>
        <codigoExcepcion xsi:nil="true" />
        <cafc xsi:nil="true" />
        <leyenda>Ley N&#176; 453: Tienes derecho a recibir informaci&#243;n sobre las caracter&#237;sticas y contenidos de los
            servicios que utilices.
        </leyenda>
        <usuario>pperez</usuario>
        <codigoDocumentoSector>1</codigoDocumentoSector>
    </cabecera>
    <detalle>
        <actividadEconomica>451010</actividadEconomica>
        <codigoProductoSin>49111</codigoProductoSin>
        <codigoProducto>JN-131231</codigoProducto>
        <descripcion>JUGO DE NARANJA EN VASO</descripcion>
        <cantidad>1</cantidad>
        <unidadMedida>1</unidadMedida>
        <precioUnitario>100</precioUnitario>
        <montoDescuento>0</montoDescuento>
        <subTotal>100</subTotal>
        <numeroSerie>124548</numeroSerie>
        <numeroImei>545454</numeroImei>
    </detalle>
<ns1:Signature><ns1:SignedInfo><ns1:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315#WithComments" /><ns1:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256" /><ns1:Reference URI=""><ns1:Transforms><ns1:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" /><ns1:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315#WithComments" /></ns1:Transforms><ns1:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" /><ns1:DigestValue>lHmci64/8XWGE3+IFjX4yeeBcnPP2KyZl6Q41MYAwFw=</ns1:DigestValue></ns1:Reference></ns1:SignedInfo><ns1:SignatureValue>WA0zeIG5E+OnPlTyGhvz0kd0RB+zCtsZUj7OkuyZduFrEnKEZGfvaRNldTCqadfeqhHqOPjCILZHEqGCN9cU90+pmnsy6nFt5jxr8cN5nAjwB9h/HMlxkLtfTG/xwskWbc22gEIiiyWLsQi2RbwIo4EKkqHXv5l1xghO74Wq3zvCv12OWaFU2ZkrJ7RyL8L0LlR5bigZ/oKtdRS5Am6vgpuVClf6lFEgeSATkY5A4DgiQ9z0ERBMc07t4Q6VAbxzFyKoFV0D9UsUjr6vZ/mS6jr3Ak3i/8IiaLrQJd9G3Qw5DqiotNWNGrQ9i5XoEPN2+cVvHMUxHe6nrmZeDHVMvw==</ns1:SignatureValue><ns1:KeyInfo><ns1:X509Data /></ns1:KeyInfo></ns1:Signature></facturaElectronicaCompraVenta>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your certificate, your certificate and key should contain the following

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```